# Cannot read property 'use' of undefined, in the passport .js file

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, node-modules

I created a folder config and i created passport.js file inside it, that holds all the configuration passport module when i tried to run my code i got this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined` referring to this line of code `passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {`

passport.js file :

```
    var express = require('express');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../server/model/userModel');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    // Local Strategy
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
        // Match Username
        let query = { username: username };
        User.findOne(query, function(err, user) {
            /*
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'No user found' });
            }
            */
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }

            // Match Password
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (isMatch) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong password' });
                }
            });


        });


    }));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });


    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: in tutorial video, they used it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use two different references for the same name.

```js
var passport = require('passport');
```

Here, you defined the passport variable.

```js
module.exports = function(passport) {
```

Here, you define the parameter name as passport. Using passport in this context will refer to the parameter

```js
passport.use(...
```

Calling on the parameter's use method instead of the passport.use method from the defined variable. Consider changing the function parameter name to something other than `passport,` maybe `_passport`?

```js
module.exports = function(passport) {
//to
module.exports = function(_passport) {
```

Comment: THANKS, BRO, REALLY APPRECIATED

Comment: No problem, Lol.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialised:

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

> To use Passport in an Express or Connect-based application, configure it with the required passport.initialize() middleware. If your application uses persistent login sessions (recommended, but not required), passport.session() middleware must also be used.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport